# How to layout images with different sizes in gallery page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, masonry

I am trying to layout images with different sizes. I tried using masonry but it doesn't work. Right now the gallery page looks like this [Gallery Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz92c.jpg)

CSS :

```
  .mediaContainerAllSizes{
        padding: 2px;
        border: 1px;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #mediaListContainer{
    width: 1200px; 
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Note: mediaListContainer is redirected from gallery.tpl file

```
<div id="mediaListContainer">
   {foreach $mediaArray as $media}
      {include file='media.container.tpl'}
    {/foreach}

 <script type="text/javascript" src="{$baseURL}/assets/javascript/masonry.pkgd.min.js">
        $('#mediaListContainer’').masonry({
                itemSelector: '.mediaContainerAllSizes',
                columnWidth: 200
            });
  </script>
```

Could I know what is the best way to layout this gallery page and why the masonry does not work?

BTW I have used this masonry file without changing anything. Do I have to change anything here at all? http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js

Answer (score 0):

I don't know masonry (or jQuery, for that matter), but after some testing with vanilla JS examples I got the hang of it. It seems that you have to set `mediaContainerAllSizes {max-size: columnWidth}` to get some kind of recognizable grid.

Check the snippet, I used your values, but the default classnames from masonry's examples.

Now you put it in your pl...

( images are courtesy of [unsplash.it](https://unsplash.it) )

```css
/* default html stuff */
html, body                  { box-sizing: border-box; height: 100%; width: 100%;
                              margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; cursor: default }
*, *:before, *:after        { box-sizing: inherit }


.grid-item {
    max-width: 400px; /*equal to 'columnWidth' in HTML data-masonry-options*/
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    background: yellow
}

.grid {
    width: 1200px; /* make 'columnWidth' a division of this width */
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 4px;
    clear: both;
    background: #f0f0f0
}

* {
    outline: 1px dotted red
}
```

```html
<!-- Only include the JS library, works automatic -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 400, "itemSelector": ".grid-item" }'>

   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/300/500?image=200"/>
   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/300/250?image=859"/>
   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/512/200?image=761"/>
   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/400/300?image=225"/>
   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/600/100?image=227"/>
   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/100/100?image=076"/>

   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/300?image=200"/>
   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/300?image=859"/>
   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/512?image=761"/>
   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/400?image=225"/>
   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/600?image=227"/>
   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/100?image=076"/>

   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/500?image=200"/>
   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/250?image=859"/>
   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/200?image=761"/>
   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/300?image=225"/>
   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/100?image=227"/>
   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/100?image=076"/>

   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/300/500?image=200"/>
   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/300/250?image=859"/>
   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/512/200?image=761"/>
   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/400/300?image=225"/>
   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/600/100?image=227"/>
   <img class="grid-item" src="https://unsplash.it/100/100?image=076"/>

</div>
```